# Source code not symbolicated in the crash report from iOS App Review

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I just got rejection from iOS app store (app name changed to ABCDApp). Here is the part of the crash report (.crash file) I got. Somehow, even thought the crash report mentioned the controller names of my app, it did not mention specific code in the crash report. For example, in the following line, it did not show which line of code created this issue. Did I miss something? I followed the upload default setting, which I believe uploads dSYM file.

```
0   ABCDApp                         0x0000000100fc2e88 0x100fb4000 + 61064
```

Here is a fragment of the report.

```
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2371 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: using title from navController:item <<UINavigationItem: 0x105f01970>: title:'(null)'> (null)
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2373 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: viewController <ABCDApp.InfoViewController: 0x105397430> ABCDApp.InfoView
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2441 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: set identifier (null) <UINavigationBar: 0x1053112f0; frame = (480 0; 480 32); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1019e9400>>
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2445 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: top most item <<UINavigationItem: 0x105326fc0>: title:'(null)'> <UINavigationBar: 0x1053112f0; frame = (480 0; 480 32); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1019e9400>>
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2446 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: using title from navController:item <<UINavigationItem: 0x105f01970>: title:'(null)'> (null)
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2448 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: viewController <ABCDApp.InfoViewController: 0x105397430> ABCDApp.InfoView
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2478 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: set identifier (null) <UINavigationBar: 0x1053112f0; frame = (480 0; 480 32); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1019e9400>>
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2482 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: top most item <<UINavigationItem: 0x105326fc0>: title:'(null)'> <UINavigationBar: 0x1053112f0; frame = (480 0; 480 32); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1019e9400>>
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2484 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: using title from navController:item <<UINavigationItem: 0x105f01970>: title:'(null)'> (null)
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2485 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: viewController <ABCDApp.InfoViewController: 0x105397430> ABCDApp.InfoView
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2503 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: set identifier (null) <UINavigationBar: 0x1053112f0; frame = (480 0; 480 32); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1019e9400>>
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2506 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: top most item <<UINavigationItem: 0x105326fc0>: title:'(null)'> <UINavigationBar: 0x1053112f0; frame = (480 0; 480 32); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x1019e9400>>
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2508 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: using title from navController:item <<UINavigationItem: 0x105f01970>: title:'(null)'> (null)
2018-03-24 23:51:33.2509 -0700  0x7009 1024 0x0 1828 UIKit: NavBar: viewController <ABCDApp.InfoViewController: 0x105397430> ABCDApp.InfoView
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ABCDApp                         0x0000000100fc2e88 0x100fb4000 + 61064
1   ABCDApp                         0x0000000100fc2eb8 0x100fb4000 + 61112
2   UIKit                           0x000000018d02e5e8 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 948 (UIViewController.m:4419)
3   UIKit                           0x000000018d09cc54 -[UIViewController __viewWillDisappear:] + 100 (UIViewController.m:4571)
4   UIKit                           0x000000018d198b2c -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1312 (UINavigationController.m:1836)
5   UIKit                           0x000000018d0bbb94 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712 (UINavigationController.m:6607)
6   UIKit                           0x000000018d0bb7d8 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 164 (UINavigationController.m:6872)
7   UIKit                           0x000000018d0bb6d8 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188 (UILayoutContainerView.m:87)
8   UIKit                           0x00000001a2dd7c18 -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility layoutSubviews] + 52 (UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility.m:114)
9   UIKit                           0x000000018d012e18 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1276 (UIView.m:15124)
10  QuartzCore                      0x0000000187a9f948 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184 (CALayer.mm:9302)
11  QuartzCore                      0x0000000187aa3ad0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 332 (CALayer.mm:9182)
12  QuartzCore                      0x0000000187a1031c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 336 (CALayer.mm:2416)
13  QuartzCore                      0x0000000187a37b40 CA::Transaction::commit() + 540 (CATransactionInternal.mm:425)
14  UIKit                           0x000000018d276a7c _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 172 (UIApplication.m:2467)
15  UIKit                           0x000000018d96dba8 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5544 (UIEventDispatcher.m:1720)
16  UIKit                           0x000000018d9667b0 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152 (UIEventDispatcher.m:1659)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a0377c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a036fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88 (CFRunLoop.c:2017)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a02f84 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a00b5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048 (CFRunLoop.c:2920)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183920c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
22  GraphicsServices                0x00000001857ccf84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
23  UIKit                           0x000000018d0795c4 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956)
24  ABCDApp                         0x0000000100fbc3ec 0x100fb4000 + 33772
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018344056c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183570d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183682eec _pthread_wqthread + 884 (pthread.c:0)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183682b6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183682b68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018354f568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018354f3e0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a03108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2613)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183a00cd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 (CFRunLoop.c:2969)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183920c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
5   Foundation                      0x0000000184355594 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001843749ac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
7   UIKit                           0x000000018dbe37a8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 (UIEventFetcher.m:437)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001844570f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996 (NSThread.m:1181)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001836842b4 _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183684180 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183682b74 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183682b68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x000000018dda8460   x2: 0x0000000000000303   x3: 0x0000000000000005
    x4: 0x0000000000000003   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000105312880   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000014   x9: 0x0000000000000012  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x00000156000001ff
   x12: 0x0000000102091a00  x13: 0x000005a1b498704f  x14: 0x0000000000404240  x15: 0x000000000000210c
   x16: 0x00000001b4987048  x17: 0x000000018db3fe98  x18: 0xfffffff00cb0125c  x19: 0x000000010530cef0
   x20: 0x0000000000000380  x21: 0x0000000102020400  x22: 0x0000000101ad92f0  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x000000018ddf33ba  x25: 0x000000000004ffff  x26: 0x0000000001402022  x27: 0x0000000000000158
   x28: 0x0000000105f4a850   fp: 0x000000016ee47d20   lr: 0x0000000100fc2e40
    sp: 0x000000016ee47cf0   pc: 0x0000000100fc2e88 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Comment: **You** need to [symbolicate it](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There should be better answers. But for the timebeing, I will show you my quick answer.

1. I am -still- not sure why my app symbols are not included in the .crash file.
2. As Paulw11 indicated, the symbolication process missed my dSYM information.
3. I could use atos to check the symbols (it is manual and a bit painful)...

   atos -arch arm64 -o ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-03-24/ABCDApp\ 3-24-18\,\ 9.55\ PM.xcarchive/dSYMs/ABCDApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/ABCDApp -l 0x100fb4000 0x0000000100fc2e88